# Waiting on a subscription in Flow Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router, flow-router

**Objective :** I want to render one among template A or template B from my flow router function, based upon a document which is retrieved **after** a subscribe call.

More specifically, I want to render either an admin or a student template based upon the *isAdmin* field of a user document, retrieved **after** a completed subscribe call. 
My router function is as shown below.

```js
FlowRouter.route('/songs/list', {
  name: 'Songs.list',
  subscriptions: function(params, queryParams) {
    this.register('getUser', Meteor.subscribe('allUsers', Meteor.userId()));
  }
  action(params, queryParams) {
    if(Meteor.user().isAdmin){
     BlazeLayout.render("admin_home");
    }
    else{
     BlazeLayout.render("student_home");
    }     
  }
});
```

The Flow router documentation mentions specifically that

> FlowRouter only deals with registration of subscriptions. It does not wait until subscription becomes ready.

So there could be a case where the "if condition" is evaluated **before** the subscription has updated the local cache.

With iron-router, this is easily handled using a waitOn. However for flow router, I am forced to have 2 separate functions, which further enforces 2 separate url's, for rendering the admin and student templates.

Is this a design choice made by the flow router developers?

Comment: You should read [Migrating from Iron Router to FlowRouter (with Blaze)](https://www.okgrow.com/posts/flow-router-migration-guide)

Answer (score 3):

Why not carry subscription logic out of routing and use [template level subscriptions](http://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) with builtin `Template.subscriptionsReady` helper?

```js
FlowRouter.route('/songs/list', {
    name: 'Songs.list',
    action: function(params) {
        BlazeLayout.render('home');
    }
});
```

```html
<template name="home">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
        {{#if isAdmin}}
            {{> admin_home}}
        {{else}}
            {{> student_home}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.home.onCreated(function() {
    this.subscribe('allUsers', Meteor.userId());
});

Template.home.helpers({
    isAdmin: function() {
        // check if user is admin
    }
});
```

This approach also [recommended in FlowRouter docs](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#subscription-management).

Answer (score 1):

Try:
    Meteor.subscribe('allUsers', {
    OnReady(){
    if(Meteor.user().isAdmin){      BlazeLayout.render("admin_home");    }   else{      BlazeLayout.render("student_home");      } }

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you're after is `FlowRouter.subsReady`, an example of how you might use it within a router (similar to IronRouter) is provided in the [docs here](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#subscription-management).

So in your case, it might look something like:

```
FlowRouter.route('/songs/list', {
    name: 'Songs.list',
    subscriptions: function(params, queryParams) {
        this.register('getUser', Meteor.subscribe('allUsers', Meteor.userId()));
    },
    action(params, queryParams) {

        Tracker.autorun(function() {

            var ready = FlowRouter.subsReady("getUser");

            Tracker.nonreactive(function(){

                if(ready && Meteor.user().isAdmin){
                    BlazeLayout.render("admin_home");
                }
                else if(ready){
                    BlazeLayout.render("student_home");
                }
                else {
                    BlazeLayout.render("loading");
                }

            });
        });
    }
});
```